# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') in Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, devops, amazon-cloudfront

I am Getting the below error while execute the Lambda function.

```
`ERROR  Invoke Error    {`
`"errorType": "TypeError",`
`"errorMessage": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')",`
`"stack": [`
`"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')",`
`"    at Runtime.handler (file:///var/task/index.mjs:14:45)",`
`"    at Runtime.handleOnceNonStreaming (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1173:29)"`
`]`
`}`
```

`But the request event defined as below`

```
`const request = event['Records'][0]['cf'];`
```

`Request response value is below`

```
`INFO   check-request**** {`
`config: {`
`distributionDomainName: 'd1cx11*******.cloudfront.net',`
`distributionId: 'E2XY*********',`
`eventType: 'origin-response',`
`requestId: '0-FIOsiWY3enUJ-mdGRSXErSx-gvchmZ9FdxFuG2oZwJvTEogHJBKw=='`
`},`
`request: {`
`clientIp: 'X.X.X.86',`
`headers: {`
`'x-forwarded-for': [Array],`
`'user-agent': [Array],`
`via: [Array],`
`pragma: [Array],`
`'sec-ch-ua': [Array],`
`'sec-ch-ua-mobile': [Array],`
`'sec-ch-ua-platform': [Array],`
`'upgrade-insecure-requests': [Array],`
`'sec-fetch-site': [Array],`
`'sec-fetch-mode': [Array],`
`'sec-fetch-user': [Array],`
`'sec-fetch-dest': [Array],`
`'accept-encoding': [Array],`
`'dealer-domain': [Array],`
`'x-forwarded-host': [Array],`
`'x-auth-dev-tpco-cepo-cdn': [Array],`
`host: [Array],`
`'cache-control': [Array]`
`},`
`method: 'GET',`
`origin: { custom: [Object] },`
`querystring: '',`
`uri: '/'`
`},`
`response: {`
`headers: {`
`date: [Array],`
`'set-cookie': [Array],`
`server: [Array],`
`'x-dispatcher': [Array],`
`'x-vhost': [Array],`
`'strict-transport-security': [Array],`
`'cache-control': [Array],`
`pragma: [Array],`
`expires: [Array],`
`vary: [Array],`
`'x-content-type-options': [Array],`
`'content-encoding': [Array],`
`'x-frame-options': [Array],`
`'content-type': [Array],`
`'content-length': [Array]`
`},`
`status: '404',`
`statusDescription: 'Not Found'`
`}`
`}`
`` ` ``
```

Comment: Not sure what you expected. The event that you posted shows no "Records" existing in it

Comment: here strangely it returning nothing inside of event, `event['Records']` is undefined or empty array and you are accesing zeroth element causing error, add handler code too for more understanding please